Exercise 4.4. from "Categories for Quantum Theory": Existence of left duals implies left-closedness
I am stuck on exercise 4.4 from Heunen and Vicary: "Categories for Quantum Theory":

Let $A$ and $B$ be objects in a monoidal category. Their exponential
is an object $B^A$ together with a map $ev: B^A \otimes A\rightarrow
 B$ such that every morphism $f: X \otimes A \rightarrow B$ allows a
unique morphism $g: X \rightarrow B^A$ with $f=ev\circ (g\otimes
 id_A$).
The category is called left closed when every pair of objects has an
exponential. Show that any monoidal category in which every object has
a left dual is left closed.

Notation: $I$ is the monoidal unit, $\alpha_{-,-,-}$ is the associator, $\rho_{-}$ is the right unitor. $-^{\ast}$ denotes the left dual, $\epsilon: A^{\ast}\otimes A \rightarrow I$ is the counit.
My thoughts: I think the exponential might be $B^A = B\otimes A^\ast$ with $ev: (B\otimes A^\ast)\otimes A \stackrel{\alpha_{B,A^\ast, A}}{\longrightarrow} B\otimes (A^\ast\otimes A)   \stackrel{id_{B} \otimes \epsilon}{\longrightarrow} B\otimes I \stackrel{\rho^{-1}_B}{\longrightarrow} B$
My question: Without any additional assumptions, I am struggling to find any morphism $X\otimes A \rightarrow B^A \otimes A$, let alone one that factors through $id_A$.
Are my thoughts about $B^A$ and $ev$ correct? If so, could someone provide a hint on how to construct $g: X \rightarrow B^A$?

Your ansatz is correct! Continuing your proof: Using left duality, to a map $f: X\otimes A\rightarrow B$ one gets a canonical map $g: X\rightarrow B\otimes A^\ast =: B^A$. Explicitly, it is given by:
$$g = (f\otimes \mathrm{id}_{A^\ast})\circ (\mathrm{id}_{X}\otimes \eta_A)$$
where $\eta_A: I \rightarrow A\otimes A^\ast$ is the coevaluation (or unit).
(I've omitted writing the associators and unitators)
One use of the duality relations gives the equation: $f = ev\circ (g\otimes \mathrm{id}_A)$.
